# Getting grayscale heightmap from Terrarium map

Tags: tiles

I'm downloading Terrarium maps from AWS S3 and I'm unable to generate a gray heightmap out of it. Does someone know the formula to translate the pixel RGB values into the grayscale (0, 255) heightmap?

The following image represents the area I'm working with

[image]

If I only use the RED pixel to generate image, I get this

[image]

You can see there some features of the mountains but it doesn't look like it should and the generated mesh looks almost flat in my 3d software.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python?

Comment: @ThomasG77 Interesting, with that I'm getting a bit more data but not with Terrarium data but with 'normal' heightmap. I am actually starting to think that my problem might not be the height itself but an 'exposure'. This grayscale might be actually correct when viewed as for the whole planet but might be too undramatic when viewed in this few KM radius

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem? Did you find a solution??